# ASP.Net MVC: Html.Editor for dictionary entries

Tags: asp.net-mvc, html-helper, asp.net-core-mvc, tag-helpers

I am trying to use `@Html.Editor` for dictionary entries, but I can't get it to work. I am running ASP.Net Core 1.0.

Example model:

```
public class TestModel
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public IDictionary<int, Fruit> Basket { get; set; }
}
```

This works fine:

```
@foreach (var key in Model.Basket.Keys)
{
    @Html.EditorFor(m => m.Basket[key])
}
```

But this does not:

```
@foreach (var key in Model.Basket.Keys)
{
    @Html.Editor($"Basket[{key}]")
}
```

In the latter the expression `Basket[1]` etc. is not resolved, and I always get a blank text box. If I force it to use my `Fruit` editor template, the model is always null.

I know it's better to use `EditorFor` whenever possible, but in my real, non-trivial application I am calling `IHtmlHelper.Editor(expression)` from inside a `TagHelper`... something like this:

```
@foreach (var key in Model.Basket.Keys)
{
    <mytaghelper for="Baskey[key]" />
}
```

And in the `TagHelper`'s `Process` method:

```
if (For != null)
{
    (_htmlHelper as HtmlHelper)?.Contextualize(ViewContext);
    tag.InnerHtml.Append(_htmlHelper.Editor(For.Name));
}
```

Although I have the `ModelExpression` ("`For`") in the `TagHelper` I don't think there's another way to call `Editor` except as I have tried it.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: you should have a look at this post :
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5424643/mvc3-html-editor-targeting-dictionary-is-not-binding-down-to-the-client

Answer (score 1):

```
  @Html.EditorFor(model => model.urDictionaryName["KeyValue"], new { htmlAttributes = new { @id = "yourId" } })
```

Or if you want it as label,you can use it as label and use hiddenfor for mapping

```
 @Html.Label(Model.urDictionaryName["KeyValue"])
 @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.urDictionaryName["KeyValue"], Model.maskDetails["KeyValue"])
```